# Random "Resource not found exception"

Tags: android, xml

I have some AnimatedVectorDrawables that I've been working with no fail for a month or so. Today I created 2 more of these avds and one of them causes this "Resource$NotFoundException".

I am accessing it the exact same way as my other avds, it is in the same location as the other avds, and I created it the same way as the other avds. The only thing that is special about this one is a "startOffset" on one of the objectAnimators. I tried removing that line but the error persists. I have tried renaming the file, copy pasting the xml into another animation that I know is working, but these all cause a crash, which leads me to think it's something within the resource xml, but I can't spot anything.

Here is the stack trace:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.swerly.mypackage:drawable/test_avd with resource ID #0x7f0700ce
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/test_avd.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0700ce
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:768)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:600)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:876)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:818)
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:605)
at com.swerly.wifiheatmap.FabHelper.setAndPlay(FabHelper.java:74)
at com.swerly.wifiheatmap.FabHelper.setupFab(FabHelper.java:65)
at com.swerly.wifiheatmap.ActivityMain.backNavigation(ActivityMain.java:82)
at com.swerly.wifiheatmap.ActivityMain.onBackPressed(ActivityMain.java:51)
at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2965)
at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2712)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3257)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:537)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:58)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:336)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:58)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:351)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4714)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4586)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4128)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4181)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4274)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4155)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4331)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4128)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4181)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4155)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4128)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4181)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4307)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4468)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2435)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1998)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1989)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2412)
at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.swerly.wifiheatmap:drawable/$test_avd__0 with resource ID #0x7f070026
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/$test_avd__0.x
```

Here is the code of the avd:
[EDIT: The issue is that the "pathData" fields weren't exported for some reason]

```
<animated-vector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
<aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
    <vector
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24"
        android:viewportHeight="24">
        <group
            android:name="group"
            android:pivotX="12"
            android:pivotY="12">
            <path
                android:name="path"
                android:pathData=""
                android:fillColor="#000000"/>
            <path
                android:name="path_1"
                android:pathData=""
                android:fillColor="#000000"/>
        </group>
    </vector>
</aapt:attr>
<target android:name="path">
    <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
        <objectAnimator
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:propertyName="pathData"
            android:duration="500"
            android:valueFrom="M 17 3 L 5 3 C 3.89 3 3 3.9 3 5 L 3 12 C 3 14.333 3 16.667 3 19 C 3 20.1 3.89 21 5 21 C 9.667 21 14.333 21 19 21 C 20.1 21 21 20.1 21 19 L 21 7 C 19.667 5.667 18.333 4.333 17 3 L 17 3 M 9 16 C 9 14.34 10.34 13 12 13 C 13.66 13 15 14.34 15 16 C 15 17.66 13.66 19 12 19 L 12 19 C 10.34 19 9 17.66 9 16 M 5 9 L 5 5 L 15 5 L 15 9 L 15 9 L 5 9"
            android:valueTo="M 7 6 L 5.6 7.4 C 7.133 8.933 8.667 10.467 10.2 12 L 5.6 16.6 C 6.067 17.067 6.533 17.533 7 18 C 7.667 17.333 8.333 16.667 9 16 C 9.667 15.333 10.333 14.667 11 14 C 11.667 13.333 12.333 12.667 13 12 L 11 10 C 10.333 9.333 9.667 8.667 9 8 L 7 6 M 8 16 C 8 16 8 16 8 16 C 8 16 8 16 8 16 C 8 16 8 16 8 16 L 8 16 C 8 16 8 16 8 16 M 8 8 L 8 8 L 8 8 L 8 8 L 8 8 L 8 8"
            android:valueType="pathType"
            android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
    </aapt:attr>
</target>
<target android:name="path_1">
    <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
        <objectAnimator
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:propertyName="pathData"
            android:startOffset="175"
            android:duration="325"
            android:valueFrom="M 17 12 L 17 12 L 17 12 L 17 12 L 17 12 L 17 12 L 17 12"
            android:valueTo="M 16.2 12 L 11.6 16.6 L 13 18 L 19 12 L 13 6 L 11.6 7.4 L 16.2 12"
            android:valueType="pathType"
            android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
    </aapt:attr>
</target>
<target android:name="group">
    <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
        <objectAnimator
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:propertyName="rotation"
            android:duration="100"
            android:valueFrom="0"
            android:valueTo="360"
            android:valueType="floatType"
            android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
    </aapt:attr>
</target>
```

Comment: no file in drawable named test_avd.xml see where you are trying to use it

Comment: I figured it out. Apparently the software I was using left the "pathData" fields empty on this export for some reason -_-

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Apparently the software I was using left the "pathData" fields empty on this export for some reason -_-